# Uploading files to node js using html form?

Tags: html, forms, node.js

```
var fs = require('fs'); // require file system module
var http = require('http'); // require http module

http.createServer(function(request,response){
var newFile = fs.createWriteStream("readme_copy.txt");
request.pipe(newFile);

request.on('end',function(){response.end('uploaded')});

}).listen(8888);
```

I am trying to use this piece of code.I am uploading a file to node server and I am creating a new copy of the uploaded file.

I mentioned My HTML file below.It is hitting the server and uploading the file but the copy of file is empty.

If I am using curl in command prompt for uploading the same file it is working fine.

Any idea what I am missing??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-8">
</head>
<body>

<form action="http://localhost:8888/">
<input type="file" name="readme.txt" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The accept attribute of the input tag is not supported in    Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Because of security issues, this example will not allow you to upload files.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript is missing the actual piece that does the writing to the readme_copy file that you created by calling createWriteStream.

Here's an example of what you need to do:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: Sorry i used the same javascript code for command 
curl --upload-file readme.txt http://localhost:8888/ and it worked i am wondering what is wrong with html